# Bonding interfaces not working

Tags: networking, ifconfig

Everytime I put in the following code (below). The problem is that network devices become unmanaged. I set the managed to true. That didn't work. when I do the ifconfig it is missing the "bond0" ip address information

```
  bonding mode=0 miimon=200

  auto lo

  iface lo inet loopback


   auto eth2

   iface eth2 inet manual

   bond-master bond0


   auto eth3

   iface eth3 inet manual

   bond-master bond0


   auto bond0

   iface bond0 inet static

   address 192.168.0.10

   netmask 255.255.255.0

   gateway 192.168.0.254

   dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1

   bond-mode 0

   post-up ifenslave bond0 eth2 eth3

   pre-down ifenslave -d bond0 eth2 eth3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here below is my working bonding configuration. Both NICs em1 & p3p1 are connecting to the same switch. BTW, it looks both NICs carries traffic rather than in "active-backup" mode.

I can see both counters on the 2 interfaces are increasing but of different rate.

```
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback 

# The primary network interface  
auto p3p1  
iface p3p1 inet manual  
        bond-master bond0  
        bond-primary p3p1  

# The secondary network interface  
auto em1  
iface em1 inet manual  
        bond-master bond0  

# Bonding Interface  
auto bond0  
iface bond0 inet static  
        address 192.168.1.99  
        netmask 255.255.255.0  
        broadcast 192.168.1.255  
        gateway 192.168.1.1  
        network 192.168.1.0  
        metric 10  
        up /sbin/ifenslave bond0 p3p1 em1  
        down /sbin/ifenslave -d bond0 p3p1 em1  
        bond-mode active-backup  
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

try spelling out the bond mode

```
bond-mode balance_rr
```

hope that helps, good luck with your bonding :)